# How to pass ID from FormBuilder to other Entity?

Tags: symfony, entity, formbuilder

I have an entity "Contract" and another entity "Currency".
How do I pass the ID of my entity Currency to my entity Contract?

For each there is a Currency ID, and this ID must be inserted in my entity Contract by FormBuilder, in the field "currency_id" in the table contract.
There onetoone entity relationship "Contract" and the entity "Currency" 
No way to rescue the Currency ID of the FormBuilder of the Contract?
I searched the documentation, but found nothing!

Here's the code of my form builder:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('currency_id', 'choice', array('label' => 'Moeda:', 'choices'  => array(''=>'', 1 => 'BRL', 2 => 'USD', 3 => 'EUR'), 'required' => true))
            ->add('safeExpenses', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'Seguro de Despesas:'))
            ->add('valueSafeExpenses', 'text', array('label' => 'Valor:'))
            ->add('safeTax', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'Seguro de Impostos:'))

        ;
    }
```

I would insert the CURRENCY_ID -> 1 - BRL, in my table Contract, in the field(column) "currency_id"

My controller:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $customer = $em->getRepository('FidcargoPortalBundle:Customer')->findAll();
        $currency = $em->getRepository('FidcargoPortalBundle:Currency')->findAll();
        $entity = new Contract();
        $entity ->setDtContract = (new \DateTime());

        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $entity ->setRegistrationStatus(Contract::AGUARDANDO_APROVACAO);
            $customer = $em->getRepository('FidcargoPortalBundle:Customer')->find($request->get('customer_id'));
            $customer = $em->getRepository('FidcargoPortalBundle:Currency')->find($request->get('currency_id'));
            $entity ->setCustomer($customer);
            $entity ->setCurrency($cusrrency);

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('contract_approve', array(
                'customer' => $customer,
                'id' => $entity->getId())));
        }
```

Comment: you have typo here $entity ->setCurrency($cusrrency);

Comment: Are you looking for the **[entity field-type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)** ? :)

Comment: The field type is ID, an external entity. 
Like I said, I'm trying to pass the ID of currency to contract entity, because in my contract there is the entity currency_id field. But it must pass the FormBuilder.

Comment: ty' pawel, i will fix now